# Hibernate foreign key change parent column

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, foreign-keys

I have 2 entity. When I want to change value in child column, it change in parent column.

First entity (User.class)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Department department;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);
    private Set<Equipment> equipment = new HashSet<Equipment>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String name, String surname, Department department, boolean enabled,
            Set<UserRole> userRole, Set<Equipment> equipment) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.department = department;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.userRole = userRole;
        this.equipment = equipment;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, length = 45)
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", length = 60)
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<UserRole> getUserRole() {
        return this.userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(Set<UserRole> userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "surname")
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "depId", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false)
    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
```

Second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
@NamedQuery(name = "allDepartments", query = "SELECT d FROM Department d")
public class Department {

    private int depId;
    private String name;
    private String adress;
    private Set<User> user = new HashSet<User>();

    public Department() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Department(int depId, String name, String adress, Set<User> user) {
        super();
        this.depId = depId;
        this.name = name;
        this.adress = adress;
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "department_id", unique = true)
    public int getDepId() {
        return depId;
    }

    public void setDepId(int depId) {
        this.depId = depId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "department")
    public Set<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Set<User> user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

My UserDAOImpl:

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl extends AbstractSessionFactory implements UserDAO {

    @Override
    public User findByUserName(String username) {
        return (User) getSession().get(User.class, username);
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(User user) {
        getSession().save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        getSession().update(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String username) {
        getSession().delete(findByUserName(username));
    }

    @Override
    public User findByDepartment(int departmentId) {
        return (User) getSession().get(User.class, departmentId);
    }

    @Override
    public Department getDepartment (int departmentId) {
        return (Department) getSession().get(Department.class, departmentId);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByName(String name) {
        return (User) getSession().get(User.class, name);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return getSession().getNamedQuery("allUsers").list();
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserSevice userService;

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentService departmentService;

    private User user;
    private Department department;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private ModelAndView updateUserPage(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("getUser", userService.findByUserName(username));
        model.setViewName("updateUser");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private ModelAndView updateUser(@ModelAttribute("users") User user, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        userService.update(user);
        model.addObject("allUsers", userService.getAllUsers());
        model.setViewName("superAdmin");
        return model;
    }
```

My jsp page:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="getUser"
                    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updateUser"
                    method="POST">
                    <!--Simple table example -->
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i>Employee
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Username:</td>
                                                <td>Password:</td>
                                                <td>Name:</td>
                                                <td>Surname:</td>
                                                <td>Enabled:</td>
                                                <td>Department:</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><form:input path="username" readonly="true" /></td>
                                                <td><form:input path="password" readonly="true" /></td>
                                                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
                                                <td><form:input path="surname" /></td>
                                                <td><form:input path="enabled" /></td>
                                                <td><form:input path="department.name" name="depName" /></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Save" name="btnSave" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
```

And I change my Controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    private ModelAndView updateUser(@RequestParam("depName") String departmentName, @ModelAttribute("users") User user,
            BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        for (Department department : departmentService.getAllDepartments()) {
            department = departmentService.findByDepartmentName(departmentName);
            user.setDepartment(department);
            userService.update(user);
        }
        model.addObject("allUsers", userService.getAllUsers());
        model.setViewName("superAdmin");
        return model;
    }
```

UserServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserSevice {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void insert(User user) {
        userDAO.insert(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void update(User user) {
        userDAO.update(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void delete(String username) {
        userDAO.delete(username);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User findByUserName(String username) {
        return userDAO.findByUserName(username);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User findByDepartment(int departmentId) {
        return userDAO.findByDepartment(departmentId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Department getDepartment(int departmentId) {
        return userDAO.getDepartment(departmentId);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User findByName(String name) {
        return userDAO.findByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userDAO.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

root case:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Head Office' for key 'UK_1t68827l97cwyxo9r1u6t4p7d'
```

What else i must show?

I get user by username. And when I want to change his department, it change all department in Department table, not in department_id column in user. How can I change user.department, not department?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want update department, remove  **updatable = false,**  from `@JoinColumn(name = "depId", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable = false)`   and use follow code to set department

```
user.setDepartment(department);    
userService.update(user);
```

or try this in UserDAOImpl:

```
@Override
public void update(User user) {
String hql = "UPDATE User set department = :department "  + 
         "WHERE username = :username";
Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);    
query.setParameter("department", user.getDepartment());    
query.setParameter("username", user.getUsername());    
int result = query.executeUpdate();
}
```

from [your Github](https://github.com/Farik013/equipment)
change UserController.updateUser to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private ModelAndView updateUser(@ModelAttribute("users") User user,
        BindingResult result) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    department = departmentService.findByDepartmentName(user.getDepartment().getName());
    user.setDepartment(department);
    userService.update(user);
    model.addObject("allUsers", userService.getAllUsers());
    model.setViewName("superAdmin");
    return model;
}
```

and DepatmentDAOImpl.findByDepartmentName to

```
@Override
public Department findByDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
    List<Department> departments = getSession()
            .createQuery("select d from Department d where d.name =:departmentName")
            .setParameter("departmentName", departmentName).list();
    return departments.size() == 0 ? null : departments.get(0);
}
```

Comment: what you get in the controller method "updateUser"?  System.out.println("dep = " + departmentName +  "username = " +  user.getUsername());

Comment: There is nothing on output. But I find one hibernate query I dont know where from this query.

{15:06:27.262 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into department (adress, name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into department (adress, name) values (?, ?)}

Comment: These queries only add department to a database, please post your UserSevices implementation

Comment: I update my post. And why it add department to a database, I don' call these method?

Comment: I'am confused with your annotation in User.getDepartment()  **CascadeType.ALL**  and  **updatable = false, insertable = false,**, i  don't know how it work together, really, remove one of these. First, debug your controller method,  what data do you receive (user and departmentName), can you find department(entity with id) by departmentName and print to console? Second, find examples with cascade and see how it work (persist, save and update), publish to Github and post link here.

Comment: Im new in Spring and Java. Sorry, but I cant do debug normally. This is my publish in Git   https://github.com/Farik013/equipment

Comment: You are can't find department, it is yous mistake.

Comment: I update answer, change UserController.updateUser and DepatmentDAOImpl.findByDepartmentName

Comment: My project dont work after git. I did everything what write in forums, but nothing helps. After issues new problem, I will try updates )) Maybe you can help me. How can I revert all project after commit on github? I try git reset --HARD, git revert. I want my initial project, without something connected with git.

Comment: and in your updated UserDAOImpl, you forget getSession.update(user). Because when this method is work, it update only department. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can set the department for the user and update the user.It will update the department id value in user table for the user.

```
user.setDepartment(department);
userService.update(user);
```